# Video Player for Free WordPress Site

Tags: video-player

I want to play video from the link to the mp4 file itself on a free wordpress site. Can you tell me how to do that

Comment: Please contact the wordpress.com support team for assistance. Thank you

Comment: You can start here: https://support.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most popular video services, you can just paste the link on a line by itself in the post editor: https://en.support.wordpress.com/videos/

For mp4 files hosted offsite on unsupported sites, you can try to use a service like this (http://embed.ly/) but I don't think it will work well. More likely, you'll have to sign up for one of WordPress.com's premium services: https://en.support.wordpress.com/videopress/

Comment: But it only YouTube, Vimeo, Hulu, Flickr, Animoto, DailyMotion, Viddler, Blip.tv, TED Talks, Educreations, Instagram, AolOn, Vine, and Videolog. I want to play the video from somewhere else. Can I do that?

Comment: Where do you want to play it from? You'll probably need their embed code, unless you can get a link to the mp4 file itself.

Comment: Yes, I want to play video with the link to the mp4 file itself

Comment: I added to my answer above.

Comment: Oh I see! So there's no other way to do it?

Comment: I don't think so.